# resizing a subview and having superviews / window resize

Tags: cocoa, nsview

My window is structured like so: NSWindow -> NSView -> NSTabView -> NSScrollView -> NSTextView. If I change the size of the NSScrollView with setFrameSize: the superviews / window do not resize to accommodate my larger or smaller NSScrollView. Is it possible to programmatically have the Window, etc. automatically resize when I set the size of a subview or do I need to somehow calculate the size of all the UI components and resize the window itself? Thanks in advance for any assistance or direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. You'll have to compute the sizes yourself. Assuming all the views in your hierarchy are set to auto-resize properly, you could just change the window's frame and let auto-resizing do its job.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Now at least I can stop searching for these non-existant methods. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a category on UIView with the following method:

```
- (void) resizeSuperviewsToContain {
    UIView* view = self;
    while(view.superview) {
        CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame);
        CGRect superViewFrame = view.superview.frame;
        if(superViewFrame.size.height < maxY) {
            superViewFrame.size.height = maxY;
            view.superview.frame = superViewFrame;
        }
        view = view.superview;
    }
}
```